# How to check the program is installed on linux?

Tags: linux, java

I want to check if the program is istalled on linux(CentOS). (I used java `jsch`)
If not, send messages to front-end which program user lacked.
I used `which`

As you can see,I didn't have `php` installed on linux.
But I'not sure whether it's a good method.   (Will it miss program?)
Please guide me.

```
[root@worker ~]# which git
/usr/bin/git
[root@worker ~]# which python
/usr/bin/python
[root@worker ~]# which php
/usr/bin/which: no php in (/usr/local/scala-2.11.6/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/root/bin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info. I can't understand what is the program you're trying to find on CentOS. You can use

```
which filename
```

to locate a command on your current environment. The command which searches your PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments you pass to it.

Example:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There were many ways to achieve this :

In general it varies based on your package ,

That depends on your distribution.

Type the following command to get list of all installed software

> rpm -qa | less

which will check for all installed programs

**Syntax** :

```
$ rpm -qa | grep {package-name}
```

**Example** :

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mutt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware on how the application was installed it would be easier.

For rpm installations you can use **rpm -qa**, which will list all packages installed with rpm installer. You can pipe grep to check a specific package.
rpm -qa|grep python

For yum installations you can try **yum list installed**. E.g. yum list installed python or yum list installed|grep python

which command gives you the path of shell components. It need not give you information on the installed packages.